# Sql calls in code behind page

Tags: asp.net

For now all my sql calls take place in the cs pages and its a lot of code my goal is to set a new class or whatever (i heard it is done right with dll's) that the class will store functions for every scenario i will need. So my question is how to accomplish it .. Suppose in a large scale site how it is supposed to be done?

Comment: I think you need to start with some very basic research. Try this: http://www.asp.net/web-forms -- follow the tutorials and watch the videos.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest creating a Class Library Project, moving your shared code to those libraries, and then including those libraries in your Web Project.

Comment: Thanks, can you point me to some article that explains the logic behind it? i did search for it but got no where...